# Matlab: How to catch warning

Tags: matlab, warnings

I am running some data processing work in MATLAB and solver uses  BACKSLASH operator. Sometimes, I get warning like this:

```
Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 1390, tol = 1.335195e-010.
Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 1386, tol = 1.333217e-010.
```

I would like to catch those warnings. 
I am trying to convert warning to error and then catch it as described here under title “Trapping warnings”:
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently
In the example, following string has been used to convert warning to error:

```
s = warning('error', 'MATLAB:DELETE:Permission');
```

However, I am not sure what string to use for my case. I tried using

```
s = warning('error', 'Warning: Rank deficient’);
```

But, it did not work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
DK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the warning *identifier*, not the warning text. You can find the identifier using the two-output form of `lastwarn`:

```
[msgstr, msgid] = lastwarn
```

In your case, I *think* the identifier you want is `'MATLAB:rankDeficientMatrix'`.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. But, could you please also explain how can I extract identifier based on displayed warning??

Comment: That's what the two-output `lastwarn` call does. You can use `dbstop if warning` if you are having trouble getting to a state where the warning you're interested in is the "last" one.

Comment: What if the warning has an empty msgid? For example, the warning 'The BytesAvailableFcn is being disabled. To enable the callback property...' has an empty msgid. I can't figure out how to turn that warning into an error!

Answer (score 7):

You could try to use [`lastwarn`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/lastwarn.html) as an alternative. After your division, call it and compare it with `strcmp` to the usual warning message, and if its the one you wnat you could manually throw the error you want with [`error`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/error.html).

As you suggested: you can reset `lastwarn` throwing an empty warning `warning('')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking the same. However, I would need to reset lastwarn as the same solver is being run many time. Can you please suggest how to reset lastwarn??

Comment: @DushyantKumar Try it and if works accept the answer so community will have a written proof to solve this problem :)

Comment: Thanks, @AnderBiguri. I just want to add that the lastwarn can be reset with: warning('')

Comment: Matlab R2014a will tell you to use `lastwarn('')` to reset the warning message!

Answer (score -1):

The following closely implements an equivalent for Python's

```py
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as ws:
    fn_out = fn()
    warn_out = ''
    for w in ws:
        if 'blah' in w.message:
            warn_out = w.message
```

It executes `fn()` twice, ensures the warning state is restored, and optionally suppresses its print statements (e.g. `disp`). Requires that the `warning()` statement used a warning ID, i.e. `warning('a:b', msg)` syntax.

#### Example

```matlab
fn = @()delete('beep');  % target function
warn_id = 'MATLAB:DELETE:FileNotFound';  % target warning ID

o = execute_and_catch_warning(fn, warn_id);  % application
[fn_out, warn_out] = o{:}  % fetch function output and warning message
```

```
fn_out =

   NaN


warn_out =

    'File 'beep' not found.'
```

#### In steps

1. Store `warning` state to restore later
2. Set `warning('off', warn_id)` to allow execution without displaying the warning
3. Execute `fn()` to fetch its output
4. Set `warning('error', warn_id)` so that next `fn()` execution triggers the warning but doesn't print it
5. Execute `fn()` again
6. Retrieve the warning via `e.message` (`catch e`)
7. Restore warning state
8. Return both the output of `fn()` and the warning message, as `out = {fn_out, warn_out}`

A little more happens (e.g. `try`-`catch`) but this is the idea.

The `fn_out` can be made optional (e.g. add another arg, and wrap the code with `if get_outputs`).

#### Code

```matlab
function [fn_out, warn_out] = execute_and_catch_warning(fn, warn_id)  %#ok<INUSD>
    s = warning;
    warning('off', warn_id);
    try
        % first try assuming `fn()` has an output
        [~, fn_out] = fn();
    catch
        % this is in case `fn()` has no output
        warning(s);  % restore prematurely in case `fn()` errors again
        fn();
        fn_out = nan;
    end

    warning('error', warn_id);
    try
        fn();  % suppress print statements
        warn_out = "";
    catch e
        warn_out = e.message;
    end
    warning(s)  % restore warning state
end
```

**Suppressing prints**: replace `fn()` everywhere with `evalc('fn()')`. *(eval is generally discouraged, but nothing stated in [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) is applicable).*