# Overflow vs Inf

Tags: c, matlab, exception, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

When I enter a number greater than max [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) in Matlab that is approximately `1.79769e+308`, for example `10^309`, it returns `Inf`. For educational purposes, I want to get overflow exception like *C* compilers that return an overflow error message, not `Inf`. My questions are:

1. Is `Inf` an overflow exception?
2. If is, why *C* compilers don't return `Inf`?
3. If not, can I get an overflow exception in Matlab?
4. Is there any difference between `Inf` and an overflow exception at all?

Also I don't want check `Inf` in Matlab and then throw an exception with `error()` function.

Comment: @lakesh What do you mean?

Comment: @lakesh I don't want calculate. Also `1e^309` is incorrect. I think you mean that `10^309=1.0e309`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's wrong with checking for an `Inf` then throwing an exception?

Comment: @David I want to do this just for learning. I want to know what is the difference between an overflow exception and an Inf ;)

Comment: This is a valid and interesting question. Those down-voting or voting to close should read up on [how the floating-point spec deals with infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Infinities) and overflow. They are commonly mixed, as in Matlab, but the two are not the same.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either.  This is a perfectly valid question, and something I'm actually curious about!

Answer (score 3):

## 1) Floating-points in C/C++

Operations on [floating-point numbers](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html) can produce results that are not numerical values. Examples:

- the result of an operation is a complex number (think `sqrt(-1.0)`)
- the result of an operation is undefined (think `1.0 / 0.0`)
- the result of an operation is too large to be represented
- an operation is performed where one of the operands is already NaN or Inf

The philosophy of IEEE754 is [to not trap](http://www.jdl.co.uk/briefings/divByZeroInCpp.html) such [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Exception_handling) by default, but to produce special values (`Inf` and `NaN`), and allow computation to continue normally without interrupting the program. It is up to the user to test for such results and treat them separately (like `isinf` and `isnan` functions in MATLAB).

There exist [two types of NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118408/what-is-difference-between-quiet-nan-and-signaling-nan) values: NaN (Quiet NaN) and sNaN (Signaling NaN). Normally all arithmetic operations of floating-point numbers will produce the quiet type (not the signaling type) when the operation cannot be successfully completed.

There are (platform-dependent) functions to [control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219244/dealing-with-floating-point-exceptions) the floating-point environment and [catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941611/can-i-make-gcc-tell-me-when-a-calculation-results-in-nan-or-inf-at-runtime) FP exceptions:

- Win32 API has [`_control87()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx) to control the FPU flags.
- POSIX/Linux systems typically [handle FP exception](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Control-Functions.html) by trapping the SIGFPE signal (see [`feenableexcept`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/feenableexcept)).
- SunOS/Solaris has its own functions as well (see chapter 4 in [Numerical Computation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/) by Sun/Oracle)
- C99/C++11 introduced the [`fenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) header with functions that control the floating-point exception flags.

For instance, check out how Python implements the FP exception control module for different platforms: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/fpectlmodule.c

## 2) Integers in C/C++

This is obviously completely different from floating-points, since integer types cannot represent Inf or NaN:

- unsigned integers use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) (so values wrap-around if the result exceeds the largest integer). This means that the result of an unsigned arithmetic operation is always "mathematically defined" and never overflows. Compare this to MATLAB which uses [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) for integers (`uint8(200) + uint8(200)` will be `uint8(255)`).
- signed integer overflow on the other hand is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105591/how-to-catch-the-integer-division-by-zero-exception-in-c-language) [division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617408/a-few-things-about-division-by-zero-in-c) [by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error) is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

### Floating Point

[MATLAB implements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) the [IEEE Standard 754](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/) for floating point operations.
This standard has five defined exceptions:

1. Invalid Operation
2. Division by Zero
3. Overflow
4. Underflow
5. Inexact

As noted by the [GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html#FP-Exceptions), these exceptions are indicated by a status word but do not terminate the program.
Instead, an exception-dependent default value is returned; the value may be an actual number or a special value Special values in MATLAB are `Inf`, `-Inf`, `NaN`, and `-0`; these MATLAB symbols are used in place of the official standard's reserved binary representations for readability and usability (a bit of nice syntactic sugar).
Operations on the special values are well-defined and operate in an intuitive way.

With this information in hand, the answers to the questions are:

1. `Inf` means that an operation was performed that raised one of the above exceptions (namely, 1, 2, or 3), and `Inf` was determined to be the default return value.
2. Depending on how the `C` program is written, what compiler is being used, and what hardware is present, [`INFINITY` and `NaN`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html) are special values that can be returned by a `C` operation.  It depends on if-and-how the IEEE-754 standard was implemented.  The C99 has IEEE-754 implementation as part of the standard, but it is ultimately up to the compiler on how the implementation works (this can be complicated by aggressive optimizations and standard options like rounding modes).
3. A return value of `Inf` or `-Inf` indicates that an Overflow exception *may* have happened, but it could also be an Invalid Operation or Division by Zero.  I don't think MATLAB will tell you which it is (though maybe you have access to that information via compiled MEX files, but I'm unfamiliar with those).
4. See answer 1.

For more fun and in-depth examples, [here is a nice PDF](http://www.ece.uah.edu/courses/ee448/chapter1.pdf).

### Integers

Integers do not behave as above in MATLAB.
If an operation on an integer of a specified bit size will exceed the maximum value of that class, it will be set to the maximum value and vice versa for negatives (if signed).
In other words, MATLAB integers do not wrap.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to repeat an answer by [*Jan Simon*](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42072-divide-by-zero#answer_51831) from the "MATLAB Answers" website:

For stopping (in debugger mode) on division-by-zero, use:

```
warning on MATLAB:divideByZero
dbstop if warning MATLAB:divideByZero
```

Similarly for stopping on taking the logarithm of zero:

```
warning on MATLAB:log:LogOfZero
dbstop if warning MATLAB:log:LogOfZero
```

and for stopping when an operation (a function call or an assignment) returns either `NaN` or `Inf`, use:

```
dbstop if naninf
```

Unfortunately the first two warnings seems to be [no longer supported](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12677-dividebyzero-warning-does-not-show-up-when-dividing-by-zero), although the last option still works for me on R2014a and is in fact [documented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#inputs).

[image: error_warning_handling_dialog1]
[image: error_warning_handling_dialog2]

Comment: Also [see this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363086/matlab-how-to-catch-warning) and this [post from Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently) on catching warnings.