# "Code within an eval statement can unexpectedly create or assign to a variable"

Tags: matlab

From [MATLAB docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html), full statement:

> Code within an eval statement can unexpectedly create or assign to a variable already in the current workspace, overwriting existing data.

What's an example?

If I define `function fn(); a=1` and call `evalc('fn()')`, could `a` suddenly appear in a variable scope other than inside of `fn`? Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77126777/10133797) (trying to figure out the -1).

Comment: You misunderstand with your example. The statements says that an arbitrary `eval()` call may cause issues, not a particularly hardcoded one. This is because it makes no sense to call `eval` in a static, known, line of code, as why would yo do `eval('a=1;)` instead of `a=1`? Its unnecesary. So any discussion of `eval` implies that you are doing `eval(some_random_string_from_somewhere_else)`

Comment: The documentatio of both `eval` and `evalc` has a nice warning explanation of it: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html

Comment: I didn't think it makes sense, but I couldn't think of any other disapproval of `evalc` in my linked example. I don't see the relevance of your linked warning.

Comment: My linked warning is there exactly for the same reason your quoted text is there, so the relevance is maximum. Code within an `eval` statement can do _anything_, including create or assign to a variable already in the current workspace. Perhaps that would be the best way to write the text in the docs. I think edric did explain well your particular case, my comment was trying to explain the general setting in which the doc you link is contextualized, as they have obviously not written that thinking on your example. It was a clarification/comment, not an answer :)

Comment: It wasn't meant as critique, but not unfair interpretation. I still see no relevance of the link to my question - if it's meant as a tip, that's fine. If your first comment interprets (and I figure it does) as a "no" to my `evalc('fn()')` query, I sought that clarified, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem that the documentation is getting at is this:

```matlab
function fn()
a = 1;
eval('a = 2;');
end
```

In this case, it's obvious that `a` will get overwritten, but it's easy to imagine more pernicious cases where the result might not be so clear. `evalin` can make things worse still.

```matlab
function fn2()
a = 1;
subfn2();
disp(a)
end
function subfn2()
evalin('caller', 'a = 2;');
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume this means the answer to _"If I define ..."_ is no (except for `evalin`).

Comment: Exactly - if you don't call `eval`, then you're in the clear.